# Beautiful Word:Hackerrank

Tags: java

**Question**
We consider a word,w , to be beautiful if the following two conditions are satisfied:

No two consecutive characters are the same.
No two consecutive characters are in the following vowel set: a, e, i, o, u, y. Note that we consider y to be a vowel in this challenge.
**For example:**

The string batman is beautiful because it satisfies the given criteria; however, apple has two consecutive occurrences of the same letter (pp) and beauty has three consecutive vowels (eau), so those words are not beautiful.

**My problem is** when i am giving an input string "yes" it prints **Yes** but it should print **No**.

When i debugged the code using Intellij i see that
It is executing the code which is past return statement but the return statement is used to transfer control to the main function.

**Solution**

```
public class Coding {
    int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Coding obj = new Coding();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String w = in .next();
        boolean b = true;
        char[] c = w.toCharArray(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 2; i++) {
            b = obj.check(i, c);  //recursive function
            if (c[i] == c[i + 1]) {
                b = false;
                break;
            }
            if (!b) {
                System.out.println("No");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (c[c.length - 2] == c[c.length - 1]) //check.for.the.remaining.chars
            System.out.println("No");
        else if (b) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
    }

    public boolean check(int i, char[] c) {
        if (c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'e' || c[i] == 'i' || c[i] == 'o' || c[i] == 'u' || c[i] == 'y') {

            count++;
            if (count == 2) {
                return false; // code following this statement are executing
            }
            check(i + 1, c);
        }

        count = 0;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `check(i + 1, c);` to `return check(i + 1, c);`?

Comment: By the rules of hackerrank event (which is in progress now) if plagiarism detected, BOTH of participants are disqualified. If someone fix and copy your solution, it will affect both of you. Maybe you should cloak somehow that this question is related to hackerrank active event.

Comment: As @DavidWallace mentioned, If you change your recursive call `check(i+1,c);` to `return check(i+1,c);` It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a recursive call, but you are ignoring the results of that call!

That doesn't make sense. Either that call is valid, then you should return whatever comes back. Or the recursion doesn't "belong" there, then you should rework the complete method!

Beyond that: although recursive solution often look elegant, those contests focus on optimal performance. Meaning: rather use a single loop to iterate that string **once**.

Comment: Oh, did I spoil it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The problem appears to be with method `count`. It always returns `true` to `main` method. If any recursive call returns `false`, is it being propagated back to main method?